# Collapse .data-target doesn't work when setting the target id, or even target class, with data from Django template tag

Tags: jquery, css, django, templates, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to collapse some content rendered in a for loop via Django template tag using bootstrap. If I hard code the collapse target, either as a Class target (data-target=".someclass") or href (href=#sometarget) I can get the function to work. However, since its a for loop, I need different targets for each 'item' so when I try and use dynamic/unique data from database as the target, bootstrap fails to collapse the content.

**Collapsable trigger**

```
{% for set in set_list %}
  {% get_comment_count for set as comment_count %}

  <!-- Title -->
    <a href="{% url 'curate:set_detail' slug=set.slug %}">
      <h1 class='title'>{{set.title}}
      </a>
      **<button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" role='button' href='#{{set.slug}}' data-target="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">**
        <i class="material-icons">
          arrow_drop_down
        </i>
      </button>
```

**Collapsable**

```
  {% for item in set.items.all %}
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 item mr-1  set-item-small"  id="multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="true">

        {% if item.type == 'video' %}
        <a href="{% url 'curate:item_detail' slug=item.slug %}"><img class='img-fluid img-preview' src="{{item.image_sized.url}}" alt="broken"> </img>
          <span class="badge badge-success badge-positioner collapse multi-collapse show">Video</span>

SOME OTHER CODE

  **<div class="collapse {{set.slug}} multi-collapse" id={{set.slug}}>**
            <a href="{% url 'curate:item_detail' slug=item.slug %}">
              <h5 class='header collapse multi-collapse'>{{item.title}}</h5>
              <a href="{% url 'curate:set_detail' slug=set.slug %}#comment_thread">{{ comment_count }} comments</a>
            </a>
          </div>
```

In the example above, I'm trying to use href targets, which don't work. I can confirm that when this renders in Google, the slug is correct. I have tried it with set.slug and set.pk, neither of which work even though the trigger href is #259 and the target id is #259. See below for similar example but using slugs.

**Collapsable rendered in Chrome

```
<div class="collapse 259 multi-collapse" id="54330-this-set-is-going-to-be-about"><a href="/items/05310-criminal-genius/">
            </a><a href="/items/05310-criminal-genius/">
              <h5 class="header collapse multi-collapse">Criminal Genius</h5>
              </a><a href="/sets/54330-this-set-is-going-to-be-about/#comment_thread">0 comments</a>

          </div>
```

**Collapse target in Chrome

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" href="#54330-this-set-is-going-to-be-about" data-target="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">
        <i class="material-icons">
          arrow_drop_down
        </i>
      </button>
```

If I alter the ID in Chrome developer tools, the collapse function starts to worK?

My jquery is loaded at the end of my base.html which the above template extends.

Comment: Ids starting with a digit are allowed, but can cause all kinds of problems with selectors etc. Prefix this numeric value with some letter, and see if it works then.

Comment: A++ ! Great! That was really bothering me, and that worked immediately. Thanks for the tip!